# The loss of my WGAN slumps to the negative infinity within just five batches(not epoch).Is there anything wrong in this WGAN code?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, distance, backpropagation, generative-adversarial-network

Here is the value of Wasserstein distance(also the Adversarial loss of GAN)

```
Epoch:0 batch_num:0 wgan_loss:-16.413176
Epoch:0 batch_num:1 wgan_loss:14472.721 
Epoch:0 batch_num:2 wgan_loss:-10957247.0
Epoch:0 batch_num:3 wgan_loss:-455000130.0 
Epoch:0 batch_num:4 wgan_loss:-3773285000.0
```

I've tried to lower the learning rate with batch size limited to 20.

The following code is what I've used for the discriminator of WGAN, which is integrated with `Gradient Reversal Layer(GRL)`.

Moreover, the `calc_coeff` function just determines the ratio of reversed gradient during the back-propagation.

```
def grl_hook(coeff):
    def fun1(grad):
        return -coeff*grad.clone()
    return fun1

def calc_coeff(iter_num, high=1.0, low=0.0, alpha=2.0, max_iter=50.0):
    return np.float(2.0 * (high - low) / (1.0 + np.exp(-alpha * iter_num / max_iter)) - (high - low) + low)

class DiscriminatorforWGAN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_feature, hidden_size):
        super(AdversarialNetworkforCDAN, self).__init__()
        self.ad_layer1 = nn.Linear(in_feature, hidden_size)
        self.ad_layer2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.ad_layer3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        self.iter_num = -1
        self.alpha = 1.0
        self.low = 0.0
        self.high = 1.0
        self.max_iter = 15.0
        self.coeff = np.float(0.02)
    def forward(self, x):
        if self.training:
            self.iter_num += 1
        if self.iter_num >= self.max_iter:
            self.iter_num = self.max_iter
        coeff = calc_coeff(self.iter_num, self.high, self.low, self.alpha, self.max_iter)
        self.coeff = coeff
        x = x * 1.0
        x.register_hook(grl_hook(coeff))
        x = self.ad_layer1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = self.ad_layer2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        y = self.ad_layer3(x)
        return y
```

As for the generator of WGAN, it's just a simple CNN-based network.
The other requirements of WGAN(such as clamping the parameters of the discriminator and the choice of RMSprop for WGAN) have been strictly followed!

The WGAN loss of mine is as follows.

```
def wgan_loss(values_from_target_side, values_from_source_side):
    W_loss = -torch.mean(values_from_target_side) + torch.mean(values_from_source_side)
    return W_loss
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the provided information, I cannot determine the exact problem for you, but here are a few hints that might help you:

1. The authors mention in a [GitHub comment](https://github.com/martinarjovsky/WassersteinGAN/issues/9#issuecomment-280989632) that you have to plot the inverse of the loss to get the plots from the paper, i.e., the Wasserstein estimate would be the inverse of your loss. This indicates that your WD approximation increases instead of decreasing as expected.

There are multiple reasons why this:

1. Have you checked how many parameters the discriminator and generator have? In contrast to a standard GAN, a WGAN discriminator should be trained to optimality. If the generator has significantly more parameters, this might be an issue. Usually, having approximately the same number of parameters is a good starting point. Without seeing your generator's code, it's impossible to see if the "strengths" are balanced.
2. How many runs per generator update do you train the discriminator for? As you want the discriminator to be trained to optimality, you usually want to run the discriminator multiple times. I have trained models where I required 30 discriminator runs per generator run for the loss to work, and I have read of others going up to 100 iterations.
3. Using gradient penalty instead of gradient clipping makes the loss much more stable in most cases. See improved Wasserstein GAN: [PyTorch Example](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/PyTorch-GAN/blob/master/implementations/wgan_gp/wgan_gp.py), [Paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00028)
4. Another trick to help the discriminator train to optimality is using BatchNorm in the discriminator. Maybe you could try this instead of dropout? [Source](https://github.com/martinarjovsky/WassersteinGAN/issues/14#issuecomment-283092028)
5. Have you ever tried to train your model for longer? I found that the Wasserstein GAN sometimes needs a few steps before it starts learning. I.e., in the beginning, the discriminator's loss peaks as it does in your case, but then it starts to behave as expected and to produce good results. See the green line in the following:
   [Example WGAN loss with initial peak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTEzh.png)